# How to troubleshoot Laravel storage root going to the wrong directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I'm migrating my Laravel implementation both from 8 to 10 and from one provider to a new PAAS.

When I'm trying to load up my index file, I'm getting the error:
file_put_contents(/app/storage/framework/sessions/...): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Notice that the directory has "/app" to start, where "/storage" should be the root directory, I believe. I do have folders there waiting and ready. I have the some environmental vars in the new host, plus I've done:

- config:cache
- storage:link
- clear-compiled
- optimize

And still nada. Still trying to go to /app/ for some reason.

I did set up my PAAS provider, Heroku, with "public" as the default web directory, but I don't believe that could make this happen. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Heroku's default root directory is "/app/", which confused the heck out of me since "app" is also a root directory in Laravel.

So the path was correct, but Heroku doesn't allow for local file storage in any case, so I needed to change the storage mechanism to redis or the DB. [Laravel/Heroku, no such file or directory for sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132003/laravel-heroku-no-such-file-or-directory-for-sessions)